# Problem with TreeNode.BeginEdit()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treenode

I'm using WinForms `TreeView` and reaction to `AfterLabelEdit` event. Here's the snippet of the code:

```
if (e.Label.Contains("|"))
{
  if (WantAutofix())
  {
    label = e.Label.Replace('|', '_');
  }
  else
  {
    e.CancelEdit = true;
    e.Node.BeginEdit();
    return;
  }
}
```

The problem is that when user doesn't want automatic fix of bad character, node doesn't stay in edit mode. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to keep in mind:

1. The `AfterLabelEdit` event always ends edit mode after it is raised, even if you call `BeginEdit` in the middle of your event handler.  You can use `TreeView.BeginInvoke` to "leapfrog" this by having EditMode start up again after the TreeView does its thing.  *(NOTE:  this does not create a new thread or race condition, it simply delays the method for 1 window message.)*  There is more information on some of the issues with this event [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/CustomizedLabelEdit.aspx) (though it suggests what I think is a worse solution).
2. `e.Label` is `null` if the user didn't make any changes, so when we "leapfrog" with BeginInvoke, it is as if the user didn't make any changes, so we also need to handle that case.
3. BeginInvoke is an acceptable workaround in this case, you should find it to be very reliable in this situation.

This works very well for me, tested with .NET 2.0:

```
    private void treeView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        //we have to handle both the first and future edits
        if ((e.Label != null && e.Label.Contains("|") || (e.Label == null && e.Node.Text.Contains("|"))))
        {
            if (WantAutofix())
            {
                e.CancelEdit = true;

                if(e.Label != null)
                    e.Node.Text = e.Label.Replace('|', '_');
                else
                    e.Node.Text = e.Node.Text.Replace('|', '_');
            }
            else
            {
                //lets the treeview finish up its OnAfterLabelEdit method
                treeView1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { e.Node.BeginEdit(); }));
            }
        }

    }

    private bool WantAutofix()
    {
        return MessageBox.Show("You entered a |, you want me to AutoFix?", String.Empty, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the BeginEdit() occur asynchronously:

```
private void treeView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, NodeLabelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Label.Contains("|"))
        {
            if (WantAutofix())
            {
            }
            else
            {
                e.CancelEdit = true;
                BeginInvoke(new ActionDelegate(new NodeBeginEditAsync(e.Node).Execute));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
public class NodeBeginEditAsync
{
    private readonly TreeNode _node;

    public NodeBeginEditAsync(TreeNode node)
    {
        _node = node;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _node.BeginEdit();
    }
}

public delegate void ActionDelegate();
```

That way the CancelEdit is given a chance to complete before a new BeginEdit tries to take over.

Comment: Not really an option: I use .NET 2.0, and this is NOT reliable solution.

Comment: Why do you think that?  (You can't use the Action() syntax perhaps, but BeginInvoke certinly works in .NET 2.0)

Comment: Simple. If this solution will work then we have a race condition - thread is created and run before CancelEdit - BAD, after it - GOOD.

Comment: I don't believe that is true.  BeginInvoke here is Control.BeginInvoke, which posts a message back to the UI thread to execute the delegate.  So, it is "asynchronous" with respect to the current call stack, but is guaranteed to execute after the current stack that is on the UI thread fully unwinds.

Answer (score 0):

Use EndEdit and Replace the "bad character" if user want automatic fix

Comment: You didn;t usderstand me. I want to stay in edit mode if he want's to fix it himself. There is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this...    
TreeNode node = tv.SelectedNode;
                    if (tv.SelectedNode.Parent == null)
                    {
                        node.TreeView.LabelEdit = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        node.Text = FieldName.Text;
                        if (node == null) { return; }
                        node.TreeView.LabelEdit = true;
                        node.BeginEdit();
                    }
```